# How to converting HEX jpg to BIN jpg

Tags: convert, image-processing

I have jpeg files, they are was saved in DB in hex format.
I import them into txt files, but files filled like this:

```
0x0000000c6a5020200d0a870a00000014667479706a703220000000006a7032200000002d6a7032680000001669686472000000580000018c0003070700000000000f636f6c7201000000000010000000006a703263ff4fff51002f00000000018c0000005800000000000000000000018c0000005800000000000000000003070101070101070101ff5c000541682bff52000c00000001010504040000ff64000b00014c52545f312e38ff90000a0000000
```

How converting this files to normal jpg for view image??

Answer (score 1):

I hope the string is a *lot* longer than that. The one you've given is barely a fragment of header. But the following should work (it did partially with your example):

```
xxd -r -p file.txt file.jpg
```

So if you've got a whole bunch of these, we can script something up to process them all:

```
find -name '*txt' -exec xxd -r -p "{}" "{}.jpg" \;
```